# How to get the result for the total duration(seconds) for the date for each invoice_no using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table

[image]

FROM TABLE DURATION

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
SELECT invoice_no, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(date), MAX(date))
FROM duration
GROUP BY invoice_no
```